# .pem file that I created from .p12 gives ssl error

Tags: ssl, openssl, apple-push-notifications, pem, p12

I try to create .pem file from .p12 file with this command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in voip_services.p12 -out voip_services.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

Previously it works fine but my pem file will expire in few days so I try to create new .pem file but this gives me ssl error

```
Error:OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca, errno 0
```

Comment: There is lots of unknown things between the command you execute and the error you get, notably that you use the certificate in an unknown way in an unknown application for unknown purpose. It is not even clear where you get this error - client or server side. Please provide way more details and context so that one can actually understand your problem.

Comment: I get this error on server when I try to use .pem file to request notification to Apple push notification server